# How can I install Ubuntu 9.10 server edition on Ubuntu 8.04 server without using a CD-ROM?

Tags: installation, ubuntu, remote-access, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-8.04

I have a server in a datacenter which uses Ubuntu 8.04 server edition. And I have a remote control for this server.

I want to delete all things in this server and install a clean Ubuntu 9.10 server edition. However, I can't put a CD in this server because it is not on my hand.

How can I format this server and install a clean (new) Ubuntu on this server without using a CD-ROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
Firstly, mount our iso

```
 sudo mount -o loop /home/ubuntu-9.04-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom0
```

Then, start upgrade

```
sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

8.04 is a LTS release. I say this not to deter you from upgrading but just to explain something. To upgrade to 9.10, you need to update to 8.10, 9.04 and then 9.10. It's a pig but the default server is quite small so there shouldn't be too many packages. It'll just take a little while.

If you waited for 10.04 (which is another LTS release), you could upgrade directly.

You can find out more about upgrading Ubuntu here: http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading

Your other option is getting somebody local to the server to write a new image to the server disk. This might be faster for you.

Comment: I'll add that upgrading isn't as messy as it is in Windows. Ubuntu does a pretty good job of cleaning up after itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can upgrade it using `apt dist-upgrade`
if you want a clean reinstall, you will need an IP-KVM of some sort

Comment: Hi.thanks for the answer. I already have something like IP-KVM so my connection doesn't closed when i restart the server. But i don't know how can i uninstall ubuntu 8.04 and how can i install ubuntu 9.04 without cd-room?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Comment: most of the IP KVMs I have used have a virtual CD drive, to which you can attach a remote .iso file. You can use that feature to reinstall the OS